# C# - Why I can't login as admin?

Tags: c#

I had a problem. I have created a login form, then in my app is using role login. Operator login was successful. But, admin login was failed, please help me.

there is my code :

```
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=buku;uid=********;pwd=********");
    public MySqlCommand cmd;

    public loginForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void login() {
        try {
            conn.Open();

            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select username, password, akses from kasir";
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            string role = reader["akses"].ToString();
            roleLogin.Text = role.ToString();

            if (usernameLogin.Text == reader["username"].ToString() && passwordLogin.Text == reader["password"].ToString()) {
                this.Hide();

                if (role.ToString() == "Operator") {
                    operatorForm op = new operatorForm();
                    op.Show();
                } if (role.ToString() == "Admin") {
                    adminForm admin = new adminForm();
                    admin.Show();
                }
            } else {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Was Wrong!");
            }

            conn.Close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        login();
    }
}
```

and this is my data from my records

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMCFr.png)

Comment: for every login, it will take the only first record. I think your table has first record with Operator role that's why it is allowed to log in.please provide data also

Comment: "passwordLogin.Text == reader["password"].ToString()" - don't store plaintext passwords!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select username, password, akses from kasir where username =" + usernameLogin.Text;
```

I think this will work you need to just put condition

Comment: @Fikri Fadillah please try this

Comment: @KavalPatel It will be better if you use SQLCommandParamters to pass the input to the Query being prepared.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the where statement to your query

```
cmd.CommandText = "select username, password, akses from kasir";
```

In addition, check if the admin role in the database is Upper or lower case to avoid any issue regarding the case-sensitive Change this:

```
if (role.ToString() == "Admin")
```

To:

```
  if(role.ToString().Equals("Admin",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not work :(